# javascript - change the alpha of an image

Tags: javascript, jquery

How can I change the alpha of an image in javascript?  Also, what browsers support this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Using jQuery:

```
$(something).css('opacity', 0.5);
```

This will work in every browser.
However, it will not work properly with semi-transparent PNG images in IE 7 and 8 unless they are applied using a filter.

Answer (score 3):

I don't think you can change the alpha of the image itself, but you can change it from the  tag, or the container in which you put it.

The particular css properties I use for this are :

```
filter:alpha(opacity=50);
-moz-opacity: 0.5;
-khtml-opacity: 0.5;
opacity: 0.5;
```

Comment: Since this question was tagged as jQuery and javascript, i am not sure he was looking for a CSS solution! (anyway, i learned something from this answer the -khtml-) Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The property's name is `opacity` and is supported by all major browsers, however in various different forms - `opacity`, `-moz-opacity` (FF pre 2.0 I think), `filter` (IE) and so on.

The easiest way to take is using a JavaScript Framework like jQuery or Prototype, they have a `.opacity()` function that takes care of the quirks.